# How to order injected files using Gulp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

My`Angular` application has the following structure

```
- src/app/main/
    |
    -main.js
    -main.controller.js
    -index.html
```

I'm using Gulp. After the build completes, the `*.js` files are injected in the wrong order in `index.html`. The file `main.js` depends on `main.controller.js`, so `main.controller.js` has to be injected before `main.js`.

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="app/main/main.js"></script>
<script src="app/main/main.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/index.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

This is my `gulpfile.js`

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var wrench = require('wrench');

var options = {
  src: 'src',
  dist: 'dist',
  tmp: '.tmp',
  e2e: 'e2e',
  errorHandler: function(title) {
    return function(err) {
      gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[' + title + ']'), err.toString());
      this.emit('end');
    };
  },
  wiredep: {
    directory: 'bower_components',
    exclude: [/jquery/, /bootstrap-sass-official\/.*\.js/, /bootstrap\.css/]
  }
};

wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file)(options);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('build');
});
```

Comment: It's not only specific to an angularjs project, it could apply to any js project. One solution is to use `gulp.src([ 'main.js', 'main.controller.js', 'some_folder/*.js, 'some_other/**/*.js''])`

Answer (score 2):

Use `gulp-angular-filesort` in your inject.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-filesort

> To work correctly, each angular file needs to have a uniquely named
>   module and setter syntax (with the brackets), i.e.
>   angular.module('myModule', []).

Example inject.js:

```
module.exports = function(options) {
  gulp.task('inject', ['scripts', 'styles'], function () {
    var injectStyles = gulp.src([
      options.tmp + '/serve/app/**/*.css',
      '!' + options.tmp + '/serve/app/vendor.css'
    ], { read: false });

    var injectScripts = gulp.src([
      options.src + '/app/**/*.js',
      '!' + options.src + '/app/**/*.spec.js',
      '!' + options.src + '/app/**/*.mock.js'
    ])
    .pipe($.angularFilesort()).on('error', options.errorHandler('AngularFilesort'));

    var injectOptions = {
      ignorePath: [options.src, options.tmp + '/serve'],
      addRootSlash: false
    };

    return gulp.src(options.src + '/*.html')
      .pipe($.inject(injectStyles, injectOptions))
      .pipe($.inject(injectScripts, injectOptions))
      .pipe(wiredep(options.wiredep))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.tmp + '/serve'));

  });
};
```

Comment: This doesn;t work for ES2015+ code as angular-file-sort  parses the entire source files and they don't support parsing ES2015+ because of  [this issue](https://github.com/klei/gulp-angular-filesort/issues/49)

Answer (score 2):

It works for me to first define the important js files in the Gulp source array:

```
var target = gulp.src('app/index.html');
var sources = gulp.src(['app/scripts/core/app.js','app/scripts/**/*.js'], {read: false});
target.pipe(inject(sources, {})).pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
```

Comment: Somewhat defeats the purpose of file injection to specify the files in order in the gulpfile. Then you have to change the gulpfile when you add a new file, which is what you were trying to avoid in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by using the [gulp-natural-sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-natural-sort) and [stream-series](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-series) modules.  `gulp-natural-sort` orders your files in a consistent order and `stream-series` takes multiple streams of files and places one before the other.

My code looks like this:

```
var series = require('stream-series');
var naturalSort = require('gulp-natural-sort');

gulp.task('inject', function() {
    log('Injecting custom scripts to index.html');

    var theseComeFirst = gulp.src(["somepath/first*.js", {read: false}).pipe(naturalSort());

    var theseComeSecond = gulp.src("somepath/second*.js", {read: false}).pipe(naturalSort());

    return gulp
        .src("*.html")
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: handleError}))
        .pipe($.inject(series(theseComeFirst, theseComeSecond), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('client/'));
});
```

You could just use the stream-series, as long as you don't care if the others are in order or not.  Unfortunately inject() will put the files in a series group in somewhat random order every time it runs, which gives me the heebee jeebees.